# Using switch with HTML button

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use switch by using HTML buttons. I have `3` buttons, tried for now only with the first button. I gave it `id=1`, and once clicked it should pass value `2` to function `switchProduct()` which will use `case:2` however, once the page loaded, the function is executing:

```
console.log('Apples are $0.32 a pound.') -
```

okay so I didn't even press the button, and it has passed value to switch once the page loaded, and when I pressing the button it's simply not working (it is not console logging anymore), it's just one time run function - how to fix it? I want to use buttons how many times I need.

**script.js**

```
let bttn = document.getElementById("1");
bttn.addEventListener("click", switchProduct(2));

function switchProduct(x)
{
    switch (x)
    {
    case 1:
        console.log('Oranges are $0.59 a pound.');
        break;
    case 2:
        console.log('Apples are $0.32 a pound.');
        break;
    case 3:
        console.log('Bananas are $0.48 a pound.');
        break;
    case 'Cherries':
        console.log('Cherries are $3.00 a pound.');
        break;
    default:
        console.log('Sorry, we are out of ');
    }
}
```

**index.html**

```
<button id="1" class="inline-block typeU">1</button>
```

Comment: The duplicate talks about `setTimeout`, but the problem is the same.  You're *invoking* a function and then passing its *result* to `addEventListener`.  Instead, pass a function itself to `addEventListener`.  The simplest approach here is likely to just wrap your function call in an anonymous function as demonstrated in the first answer on the duplicate.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now i get the problem

Answer (score 1):

This is because of a mistake in the event listener you add:

```
bttn.addEventListener("click", switchProduct(2));
```

This adds the *result* of `switchProduct(2)` as the event listener to the `click` event of the button.

Instead you need to use an anonymous function to wrap the call to `switchProduct(2)`:

```
bttn.addEventListener("click", function() { switchProduct(2); });
```

See here in this working snippet:

```js
let bttn = document.getElementById("1");
bttn.addEventListener("click", function() { switchProduct(2); });

function switchProduct(x){
    switch (x) {
        case 1:
            console.log('Oranges are $0.59 a pound.');
            break;
        case 2:
            console.log('Apples are $0.32 a pound.');
            break;
        case 3:
            console.log('Bananas are $0.48 a pound.');
            break;
        case 'Cherries':
            console.log('Cherries are $3.00 a pound.');
            break;
        default:
            console.log('Sorry, we are out of ');
    }
}
```

```html
    <button id="1" class="inline-block typeU">1</button>
```

Comment: Briliant Martin, Thank you so much!